# How to specify installation path of docker on CentOS6.5?

Tags: docker

I'm a beginner of docker,I use CentOS6.5.

I want to specify installation path of docker.

I want to know how to install the Docker CE version and how to install it into specified path?

For example,this path:`/opt/docker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [official docker instruction](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/) to install docker-ce on CentOS.
For installing in a specific path, you can use `yum install` command with `--installroot=root` switch. Something like this:

```
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io --installroot=/opt/docker
```

Comment: When I use the command as you said `sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io --installroot=/opt/docker`,the error message is:`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /opt/docker/var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again`

Comment: Did you follow the link on how to add docker repository on CentOS?

Comment: Yes,first I use this command `sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2`,then I use `sudo yum-config-manager  --add-repo   https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo`,last,I use `sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io --installroot=/opt/docker`

Comment: set--releasever=/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a mistake like this:

> Error: Package: docker-ce-18.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64
>   (docker-ce-edge)
>              Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Then I use this command to fix it.

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo http://mirrors.aliyun.com/repo/Centos-7.repo
```

After that,I use this command to install docker,`yum -y install docker-io`,I need run the command on centOS6.

Then there is no error.